# strtof() producing weird results in C

Tags: c, string, floating-point, token

first of all, compiling with flags -Wall, -ansi, -pedantic. no warnings or errors. and no debugging is helping.

basically my code is working fine however returning very weird and unexpected results when I turn a token from a string to a float using strtof()

the section of code below is:

```
 printf("token is %s\n", token);
 newstockdata->unitPrice = strtof(token, NULL);
 printf("price is %d\n", newstockdata->unitPrice);
```

newstockdata is allocated to the correct size: unitPrice is a float variable: the first printf statement prints "150.00": the second printf statement prints "0" but after a few iterations it returns a really long consistent number. any help please?

Comment: Any time I read "weird and unexpected" in an unmanaged language, I immediately think uninitialized memory use.

Comment: You have %d (integer) in your printf.  Would probably work better with %.2f.

Comment: I agree it definitly looks like it, but no idea how it is happening

Comment: I agree with @jamesqf - if the OP is curious, here's what you're likely seeing being interpreted as a decimal -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory

Comment: i.e. -- try `printf("price is %.2f\n", newstockdata->unitPrice);`

Comment: what about overflow? Did you check the errno?

Comment: you're right, I didn't realize the additional points overflowed so far if you didn't determine how many points it needed to store, thanks. if you wrote that out as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @jamesqf write your answer as an aswer, rather than a comment

Comment: @RoryThoman there is no overflow or "additional points overflowed" (whatever that means), you just used the wrong format specifier for printf

Comment: @Matt McNabb: I don't actually know that it's an answer until the OP tries it...

Comment: @RonDahlgren that is only with an old ABI where printf parameters are passed on the stack.

Comment: @jamesqf there's no question that using `%d` to print a float is a mistake. (Possibly there are *also* more errors in other code that wasn't shown, but we can only answer based on what was posted)

Comment: Unrelated to the question proper: you *really* don't want to be using floats to store anything to do with money. This will bite you bad in the long (actually, even short) run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to handle overflow cases. After calling `strtof()` check `errno` for overflow. If you think the values could be very long, you can use `double` or `long double`.

Comment: thanks, didn't know strtof() caused overflow if you don't determine how many values past point.

Comment: But the OP prints out the string being passed to strtof, and it's "150.00", so overflow is not likely here.

Comment: The format specifier should have been %f. But he says after a few iterations a long number is printed. So I suspect this as a case of value overflow.

Comment: @Kishore he is accessing invalid memory by using the wrong format specifier so it is probably just printing garbage

Comment: ya. even that is possible. but then shouldn't he be getting a segmentation fault if he is accessing invalid memory?

Comment: I don't think so since the memory is allocated, just not clean.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: It looks like the memory should be valid - just printing out the bytes of float 150.0 as an int.  I can't see why it would change after several iterations (I'd think it should always be the same), but the OP doesn't supply the code for the iterations, so who knows?

Comment: @jamesqf `int` could be larger than `float` on his system, or they could be passed in a different register, or anything really

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here, assuming that `unitPrice` is a `float`:

```
printf("price is %d\n", newstockdata->unitPrice);
```

To print a `float` you must use the `%f` specifier. Otherwise, it is undefined behaviour and anything could happen.

---

A possible explanation of the changing values you see might be that your system passes floats in a different register to ints.  The `printf` receiving `%d` is looking in a register that is never set, so you are seeing whatever value was left over from some previous operation.

This is actually pretty common, [here is an example](http://goo.gl/HI2aGJ) - `%esi` is used for the `int`, and `%xmm0` is used for the floating-point value.